# Getting empty contents in the Postman API when filtering through Spring data Specification

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm using the Spring Data JPA Specifications for Filtering data.

But When i'm hitting this URL http://localhost:9091/api/student/all?salary_like=1500

if i'm filtering through name also getting empty contents.

[image]

i'm getting the empty contents here.

But in eclipse console it's generating the correct query:

```
Hibernate: select student0_.id as id1_0_, student0_.address as address2_0_, student0_.age as age3_0_, student0_.name as name4_0_, student0_.salary as salary5_0_ from student_data_with_projection student0_ where (student0_.name like ?) and (student0_.age like ?) and (student0_.address like ?) and student0_.salary=1500.0 limit ?
```

And My code is:

**POJO**

```
@Data
@Component
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@Table(name = "student_data_with_projection")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private int age;

    @Column(name = "salary")
    private Float salary;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/student/") //This is a Base URL in Our Controller.
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @GetMapping(path = "all")
    public @ResponseBody
    Iterable<Student> getAllStudentWIthProjection(@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "") String name_like,
                                                  @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "") int age_like,
                                                  @RequestParam(required = false) Float salary_like,
                                                  @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "") String address_like,
                                                  @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "0") int pageNum,
                                                  @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "20") int pageSize) {

        StudentSpecification spec1 =
                new StudentSpecification(new SearchCriteria("name", ":", name_like));

        StudentSpecification spec2 =
                new StudentSpecification(new SearchCriteria("age", ":", age_like));

        StudentSpecification spec3 =
                new StudentSpecification(new SearchCriteria("address", ":", address_like));

        Specification<Student> specGroup = Specification.where(spec1).and(spec2).and(spec3);

        if (salary_like != null) {
            StudentSpecification spec4 =
                    new StudentSpecification(new SearchCriteria("salary", ":", salary_like));
            specGroup = specGroup.and(spec4);
        }

        Page<Student> findAll = studentRepository.findAll(specGroup, PageRequest.of(pageNum, pageSize));
        return findAll;

    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
public interface StudentRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Student, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Student> {
}
```

**Specification**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class StudentSpecification implements Specification<Student> {


    private SearchCriteria criteria;

    public StudentSpecification(SearchCriteria searchCriteria) {
        super();
        this.criteria=searchCriteria;
    }

    public SearchCriteria getCriteria() {
        return criteria;
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate
            (Root<Student> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {

        if (criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(">")) {
            if (root.get(criteria.getKey()).getJavaType() == Date.class) {
                return builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.<Date>get(criteria.getKey()), (Date)criteria.getValue());
            } else {
                return builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(
                        root.<String> get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue().toString());
            }
        }
        else if (criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase("<")) {
            if (root.get(criteria.getKey()).getJavaType() == Date.class) {
                return builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.<Date>get(criteria.getKey()), (Date)criteria.getValue());
            } else {
                return builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(
                        root.<String> get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue().toString());
            }
        }
        else if (criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(":")) {
            if (root.get(criteria.getKey()).getJavaType() == String.class) {
                return builder.like(
                        root.<String>get(criteria.getKey()), "%" + criteria.getValue() + "%");
            } else {
                return builder.equal(root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Criteria**

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SearchCriteria {
    private String key;
    private String operation;
    private Object value;

    public SearchCriteria(String key, String operation, Object value) {
        super();
        this.key = key;
        this.operation = operation;
        this.value = value;
    }

    /* Getter and Setter */

}
```

[image]

I have uploaded the  code in GitHub: https://github.com/avinashm294/Filters.git

How can i fix this to filter my data.

Comment: do you have anyhing in your DB that matches the criteria and should be returned?

Comment: Yes i have the correct data in my db. and i have updated my post with screenshot @NirLevy

Comment: Now i'm able to get the contents when i filter the data using "=" like **http://localhost:9091/api/student/all?age_like=25**, but it's not working for less than(<) and greater than(>) for example: **http://localhost:9091/api/Student/all?age_like<25**

Answer (score 1):

I had used the @Getter and @Setter annotation of lombok in the POJO which was not working. After Adding the getter and setter explicitly now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

the like in the query work as = 
you need to append % before and after the name 
example

```
StudentSpecification spec1 =
            new StudentSpecification(new SearchCriteria("name", ":", "%"+name_like+"%"));
```

Comment: No still i'm not able to see any contents in postMan API @Mohammad Shrateh

Comment: oh 
you should provide your POJO class with setter and getter